# Why there are so many difference among different versions of hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, maven

I am confusing about that so many differences between versions of hibernate.
I am doing a example of SSH according some tutorials. From my point of view, there should be less difference among them just like the Struts2. It's reasonable that some changes occur between versions.
In the example, I choose the hibernate-3.6.10.Final, but I found that it can not fit the example. Below is requisite:

> hibernate-annotations.jar
>
> hibernate3.jar
>
> hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
>
> ejb3-persistence.jar
>
> hibernate-core.jar

I can't find any of them in the hibernate-3.6.10.Final, but in other versions files. Is this situation normal when we develop using hibernate? Or something I am wrong with ?
BTW, I use maven to build my project, would it be wrong with my repository?

Comment: Many share your pain. I think your observations are pretty accurate. Hibernate is split in a number of relevant libraries, even though `hibernate3.jar` appears to bundle a bunch of these, and the version numbers of the different libraries don't always make sense in relation to each other. I've not found another way than trial, error and digging through their POM files to find hints about what to combine.